# Running devtools::check() on Rstudio results in 0 notes/ 0 errors/ 0 warnings; but running R CMD check gives me errors and notes

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, anaconda, cran

I am using Rstudio-version 0.99.902 and R-version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21).

I have written a package that I would like to submit to CRAN. When I run the `devtools::check()` functions (--as-cran included), I successfully **pass all tests**, with **NO** errors/warnings/notes.

Although when I run the same on my terminal (ubuntu 15.10), it gives me errors and warnings.

Running `R CMD build` -

```
R CMD build  mypackage
//home/akilesh/anaconda2/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/home/akilesh/anaconda2/lib/R/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator
* checking for file ‘mypackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* preparing ‘mypackage’:
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* checking for LF line-endings in source and make files
* checking for empty or unneeded directories
* building ‘mypackage_0.1.0.tar.gz’
```

Running `R CMD check` -

```
R CMD check mypackages_0.1.0.tar.gz 
/home/akilesh/anaconda2/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator
/home/akilesh/anaconda2/lib/R/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator
* using log directory                '/home/akilesh/Desktop/CRAN/final/mypackage.Rcheck'
* using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
* using platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘mypackage/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package ‘mypackage’ version ‘0.1.0’
* package encoding: UTF-8
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking for hidden files and directories ... OK
* checking for portable file names ... OK
* checking for sufficient/correct file permissions ... OK
* checking whether package ‘mypackage’ can be installed ... OK
* checking installed package size ... OK
* checking package directory ... OK
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... ERROR
/home/akilesh/anaconda2/lib/R/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator
* DONE

Status: 1 ERROR
See
‘/home/akilesh/Desktop/CRAN/final/mypackage.Rcheck/00check.log’
for details.
```

This is my `DESCRIPTION` file

```
Package: mypackage
Type: Package
Title: package title
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Akilesh [aut,cr]
Maintainer: Akilesh <myemailid@gmail.com>
Description: My package description.
License: GPL-2
LazyData: FALSE
Imports:
    rvest,dplyr,httr,stringr,jsonlite,glue,xml2
Suggests:
    knitr
RoxygenNote: 6.0.1
Encoding: UTF-8
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening. Can I still submit my package to CRAN, since it passes the tests while running on Rstudio, `devtools::check()`? And while it passes all test while running on Rstudio, why isn't it passing the tests on the terminal? Does it have something to do with installing `Conda`?

What is the significance of the `/home/akilesh/anaconda2/lib/R/bin/R: 12: [: Linux: unexpected operator` error?

`UPDATE`: Added the minimum version numbers for R, and all Imports as well. In vain.

Comment: A guess: is it the `Author` line?

Comment: try with `Authors@R: c(person("Akilesh", , , "myemailid@gmail.com", c("aut", "cre")))`. Reference: [Advanced R - packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html#description)

Comment: @SymbolixAU I tried doing that, still getting an error. Perhaps its coz of the R version I am using? 
`Required fields missing or empty:
  ‘Author’ ‘Maintainer’
* DONE`

Comment: Ran it again with some minor changes in description file, with your suggestions, same error as the question. @SymbolixAU

Comment: Sounds like you're testing the source, rather than the tarball built with `R CMD build`. If you do as @SymbolixAU suggests (removing the Author and Maintainer lines entirely), build, and then check, I imagine you won't have problems. Your license should also be `License: GPL (>= 2)`.

Comment: Removing author and maintainer gives me a missing fields error. (as expected) Changing GPL to the format suggested by you doesn't change the result either. Using Authors@R doesn't work either. I've given up. :(

Comment: Try creating and building a brand new, empty package created with just the bare-bones code and DESCRIPTION that RStudio generates

Comment: Yep did that, same error. Definitely an issue with R/Conda, some clash. Checks perfectly on Rstudio, not on the terminal. Weird.