# devtools Authors@R Error: 'Authors' not found

Tags: r, devtools

I am rebuilding our current R package using devtools, but am coming across an issue with Authors@R field.

I am following the instructions in the Writing R packages book i.e:

```
Authors@R: c(person("Hadley","Wickham", email ="hadley@rstudio.com", role = "cre"),person("Winston","Chang", email ="winston@rstudio.com", role ="aut"))
```

But get the error message:

```
Error: object 'Authors' not found
```

Devtools is loaded in, and I'm using RStudio. Have had a look around for that error message with no success. Any one have any ideas how I can get around that?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you actually did. That line in the package DESCRIPTION file is just text. I don't think if was supposed to be executable in any sense.

Comment: is [this the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44740211/5977215) ? Is your package on github or somewhere else to view?

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe I've misunderstood the guidance in the book, and just need to modify the description file rather than update from the command line as you can other fields. @SymbolixAU Thanks for your help, haven't quite got as far as building it yet

Answer (score 0):

I had same probrem.
but
below the line

author：Hadley Wickham [aut、cre]

add this line &rebuild
perhaps OK!

Comment: Your answer is not understandable. Can you please read this FAQ on how to answer questions (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), clarify your comment, and include the exact code you are suggesting (formatting tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Also, please read the comments on the original question: it appears the original problem was not with coding, but with understanding the instructions.